# getting this error SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 10.xxx.xx.xxx, port = 43620 in flutter

Tags: sockets, http

on Emulator it's working fine, but on real devices getting this error all time of incorrect port assigned.

in flutter project deinfed local IP address. sometimes getting this error mostly in real devices.